# Testing onUpdate results in TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have recently migrated my Firebase Functions from beta to 1.0.2 and in the process wrote a bunch of unit tests using the new Firebase Test SDK for Cloud Functions. Some of my functions are responsible for mirroring data from Realtime to Firestore and as such I have used the **onUpdate()** Realtime Database trigger which provides **change** and **context** objects. My issue is, in testing these I get the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined** because the **after** and **before** properties of the change object are undefined. These functions work when deployed, it's only during testing that this error crops up. One of the functions showing this issue is:

```
exports.mirrorTransactionUpdates = functions.database.ref("transactions/{id}").onUpdate((change, context) => {
    return firestore.collection("transactions").doc(context.params.id).set(change.after.val());
});
```

and the unit test is:

```
describe("mirrorTransactionUpdates", () => {
    it("should update transactions in firestore", () => {
        const data = {date: 1};
        const snapshot = test.database.makeDataSnapshot(data, "transactions/test_transaction_id");
        return test.wrap(activeFunctions.mirrorTransactionUpdates)(snapshot, {
            params: {id: "test_transaction_id"}
        }).then(() => {
            return firestore.collection("transactions").doc("test_transaction_id").get()
                .then(mirroredDoc => {
                    assert.deepEqual(mirroredDoc.data(), data);
                });
        });
    });
});
```

I cannot find anywhere why the change.before and change.after are not defined when unit testing. I also do not see anywhere in the docs where I can/have to define them myself. It should be noted that this also happens with the **onWrite()** event handler. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am using firebase-admin 5.11.0 and firebase-functions 1.0.2

Comment: Did you figure it out?